# use rbenv to set global ruby version fail

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Now I am trying to install ruby using rbenv, while after install ruby and set it to the global.But when I type "ruby -v" I got following text:

```
root@AY1211020841143c65372:~# rbenv install 1.9.3-p392
Downloading yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/36c852831d02cf90508c29852361d01b
Installing yaml-0.1.4...
Installed yaml-0.1.4 to /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392

Downloading ruby-1.9.3-p392.tar.gz...
-> http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.3-p392.tar.gz

Installing ruby-1.9.3-p392...

Installed ruby-1.9.3-p392 to /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392

root@AY1211020841143c65372:~# 
root@AY1211020841143c65372:~# 
root@AY1211020841143c65372:~# rbenv global 1.9.3-p125
rbenv: version `1.9.3-p125' not installed
root@AY1211020841143c65372:~# rbenv global 1.9.3-p392
root@AY1211020841143c65372:~# ruby -v
The program 'ruby' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby1.8
 * ruby1.9.1
Try: apt-get install <selected package>
```

Comment: Did you run `rbenv rehash` ?

Comment: which version of rbenv is?

Comment: @ProGNOMmers rbenv -v : * 1.9.3-p392 (set by /root/.rbenv/version)

Comment: after rbenv rehash : rbenv 0.4.0-45-g060f141

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps  I use this post to config my rails environment

Comment: Try this: `rbenv local 1.9.3-p392`. Will solve the problem that you are seeing for now.

Comment: I would try to uninstall the rbenv package (which probably is outdated) and use from github (https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/)